# How to disable spell checking in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I tried the following settings, but all it did was make things progressively worse.

```
"spell_check": false,
"dictionary": "",
"spelling_selector": "",
```

I don't understand the default value of `spelling_selector`, but maybe that's the key?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You need to explain *`all it did was make things progressively worse`* in detail.

Comment: @MattDMo Well, the squiggly red lines are bothering me. When I changed the settings there were more squiggly red lines. It's more of a nuisance than a real problem. :)

Comment: If you press `f6` you toggle spell checking per view and the view settings overwrite the user settings. Hence just pressing `f6` might solve your problem.

Comment: changing the selector to an empty string means every scope will be spell checked. Better to use `non-existing-scope` or `-text -source` instead.

Answer (score 45):

Press `F6` to toggle `Spell Check`

You can also find it under `View > Spell Check`

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 34):

This is what setting 'spell_check' in your `preferences - user` or `syntax specific - user` preference file does:

```
// Set to true to turn spell checking on by default
    "spell_check": false,
```

Note that you are changing the DEFAULT status of spell checking.

To toggle the ACTUAL status of spell checking use F6.

If you set your default value to 'false' (simply remove all reference to spell checking in all your `preferences - user` or `syntax specific - user` preference files to allow the `preferences - default` of `false` to apply everywhere) and toggle spell checking to OFF using F6 then you should no longer see those red spell check markers anywhere.

I'd suggest removing the changes you made to `"dictionary":` and  `"spelling_selector":` since you don't understand what they are for and they won't do what you want (as your own experiments have proven). I assume you made the changes you listed in your `preferences - user` and possibly `syntax specific - user` preference files so just delete them and let the `preferences - default` settings apply as originally set for you.

Basically using the F6 toggle is the answer you are looking for.