# Sublime editor per line code shows an annoying red underline

Tags: sublimetext3

How can I get rid of annoying color red like underline per code line on Sublime editor? It suddenly appeared this morning, and it's very annoying.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable spell checking in Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529838/how-to-disable-spell-checking-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: I don't think that's spell checking because there are only 10 misspelled words but there are more than 10 regions portrayed here. Do you get any hover popups that tell you what's wrong? This looks like the word of a third party package that is having issues with your code. I've seen this happen with the TypeScript package from Microsoft, for example.

Comment: This has also been [mentioned recently](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/remove-syntax-highlight-red-wavy-underlines-everywhere/41663) on the forum as well.